# Multiple Aggregate Ratings of Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I have multiple aggregate ratings snippets in one page.

Is there a way to make one of them the default one? The one that will be displayed in the results of Search Engines?

Thanks all!

Update:
That webpage is, essentially, the page of a Brand.
It contains the aggregate ratings of the Reviews of the Brand and a list of its products (with aggregate rating for each product).
Of course the link is like www.site.com/brand, so the main aggregate rating have to be the Brand one.

Comment: Is this page about the thing that gets rated, or is it a page that only contains the ratings (and the rated thing has another page)?

Comment: The page is, essentially, the page of a Brand.
It contains the aggregate ratings of the Reviews of the Brand and after a list of its products (with aggregate rating for each product).
Of course the link is like www.site.com/brand, so the main aggregate rating have to be the Brand one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly denote which entity should be used for purposes like Rich Snippets.
But you can try it indirectly, by denoting what the page is about (what consumers, like Google Search, do with this information is up to them).

In your case, the page seems to be about the brand. Not sure if you are really using [`Brand`](http://schema.org/Brand), but this type misses some essential properties, so here I’m using [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) (which can have a `Brand` via the [`brand` property](http://schema.org/brand)).

You might have something like this:

```
Product → manufacturer → Organization
Product → aggregateRating → AggregateRating 

Organization → aggregateRating → AggregateRating
```

By specifying what the current page is about, consumers might deduce which Rich Snippet (or similar) to show. Currently this can be done with the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about):

```
WebPage → about → Organization
```

So consumers might understand that this is a page about the organization, so the organization’s rating is more relevant than the ratings of the organization’s products.

In the next Schema.org version, we get two new properties:

- `mainEntity` ([draft](http://sdo-gozer.appspot.com/mainEntity)): "Indicates the primary entity described in some page or other CreativeWork."
- `mainEntityOfPage` ([draft](http://sdo-gozer.appspot.com/mainEntityOfPage)): "Indicates a page (or other CreativeWork) for which this thing is the main entity being described."

So then you could specify that the brand‘s `AggregateRating` is the main entity. However, I’d still say that not the rating should be the main entity, but the brand/organization.